# sending Kafka-connector logs/events to NewRelic

Tags: debugging, logging, events, apache-kafka-connect, newrelic

Currently we are using kafka connector to get data from a source which is happening fine as expected, now I am planning to send the kafka-connector logs/events to NewRelic for better debugging.

**Is there a way to let kafka connect send the connector logs to Newrelic? and if so ow to achieve this**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can implement the [New Relic Sink Collector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/newrelic/newrelic-kafka-connector)

More Links:

- https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/kafka-connect-for-new-relic
- https://docs.newrelic.com/whats-new/2020/10/kafka-connect-unlock-open-source-alternative-instrumentation-sources/